# How to profile a GUI application with a message queue?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, message-queue, profiler

I would like to profile a GUI application that uses a  message queue. In the profiler results window I see that 80% of the samples are within message loop handling code. Is it possible to filter out the results somehow that I only see the code I can influence?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 C++ profiler.

Comment: if most of the time is being spent in the message loop it would seem that there is not much performance improvement to be had. are you seeing a problem with GUI responsiveness?  there are other data collection methods that you can use and perhaps sampling is not a good approach for your application.  see [How to: Choose Collection Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182374.aspx) which is for VS 2015 but probably would be helpful with VS 2013.

Comment: so, you mean to say, some part of application is handled by you and the message queue handling thread/code is not under  your control??

Comment: @basav In the application code I just have event handlers e.g. MyFancyButton::OnButtonClicked and the GUI framwork (wxWidgets in my case) implements message queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I might do is take each event handler and put a temporary outer loop in it, to make it take a lot longer than it normally would.
It needs to run long enough that [*manual sampling*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) can be used.

This allows finding any possible speedups in the event handlers.
After those are fixed, the outer loops are removed, and the code flies!